# How to build a graphic multi-dimensional arrays

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, multidimensional-array, uicollectionview

I want to create a graphic multi-dimensional array like this :

[Doodle imag](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/843/img0837u.png/)

I saw collection-view but I never use it so I don't know if it can be efficient for what I want. Maybe a library exist ?

What is the best way to create this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UICollectionView` is good for displaying data in a grid-like manner, so I think it'll fit your purpose well. The only caveat is that it is a class introduced with a very recent version of iOS (iOS 6). If you want your app to run on previous versions of iOS as well, you may want to take a look at some of the open source clones of `UICollectionView`, for example: https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView

Comment: +1, You can also do this with a UITableView and custom cells if you want to support older versions of iOS.

Comment: @lnafziger Good suggestion. If the OP wants to know more about using a UITableView with custom cells from a storyboard, here's a link to the documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW20